# How do you retrieve up to 3200 statuses in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter, paging

**Background**
Building a rails app that gets another user's statuses to store into my database
Using gem 'twitter'

Using the module methods, I can call Twitter.user_timeline("username", count: 3200)but it will retrieve at most 200 statuses.

**Questions**
Does there exist a method or code using the gem where I can exceed this limit? or how can i page through my statuses beyond 200?

I have researched that you can reach up to 3200 statuses.  I am not looking to exceed it but at least reach the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is the code I used along with comments, using max_id as a paramater, running it through the loop then saving it to the database. Hope this is helpful for someone

// get initial resposne

//this will return 20 results

```
x = Twitter.user_timeline("username")
```

//save each result the database

```
for i in(0..x.length-1)
    tweet = Tweet.create
    tweet.info = x[i].whatever_info
    tweet.save
end
```

//now get the last tweet_id and pass it into max_id as part of the request

```
last_id = x.last.id  
prev_id = 0
```

//now you want to pass the last_id into a new request and loop it until the last_id is equal to the previous_id

```
while prev_id != last_id do
a = Twitter.user_timeline("username", max_count: 200, max_id: last_id)
    for i in(0..x.length-1)
        tweet = Favoritetweet.create
        tweet.info = a[i].whatever_info
        tweet.save
    end

    prev_id = last_id
    last_id = x.last.id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only retrieve 200 at a time, the documentation seems to suggest you can use the parameter :max_id to get older statuses. 3200 statuses is as far back as you can go